# Либа на c++ для архивирования

Tags: библиотеки, c++

Требуется простая в использовании библиотека для архивации и разорхивации файлов и папок. Возможно какая то модифицированная `zlib`. Либо что нибудь еще не слишком громоздкое.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Есть сишная либа [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/)

И вот такое [7-zip sdk](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).

И то, и другое по 500 килобайт.

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать LZO за простоту, скорость и хорошее сжатие. Есть вариант в виде всего двух файликов, .c и .h. Порядка 50 КБ.

Но она, насколько я знаю, предназначена только для текстов и не работает с директориями/файлами (только с массивами байт).